# Entity Framework Core 5.0 ColumnsBuilder set default type = null

Tags: c#, ef-core-5.0

```
    [Table("Items")]
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
```

EF Core 3.1 and early generate code

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Items",
                schema: "dbo",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    ItemName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Items", x => x.Id);
                });
```

EF Core 5.0 generate code with DB type

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Items",
                schema: "dbo",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ItemName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(200)", maxLength: 200, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Items", x => x.Id);
                });
```

How to configure ModelBuilder not to specify type in ColumnsBuilder?
Type = null allows you to use 1 migration for several DB servers.
Manual deletion of data type from migration is not correct.